# Values that written in the CSV file is on a loop. I only need one single string (Jmeter)

Tags: regex, csv, jmeter, beanshell, post-processing

I have written a simple beanshell script to get few values that I have selected with a regular expression and write them into a CSV file in a string.

```
nic = vars.get("NicNo01");
name = vars.get("Name01");
loanId = vars.get("Loan_Id");

f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/scripts/Final/result.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print(nic + "," + name + "," + loanId);
f.close();
```

The data is been written in a loop with few null values and at the end the final string is the correct one I need. I have not used any loop controllers or the thread group is not on a loop. This is a part of the CSV file data.

```
null,null,null
null,null,null
588583492V,A B C Fernando,null
588583492V,A B C Fernando,null
588583492V,A B C Fernando,null
588583492V,A B C Fernando,127180
```

why is there a loop like data export? And How can I get only the correct final string?

Comment: Do you need the records which have all the 3 fields?

Comment: I really need the 3 values that is been assigned to the variables at the top to be recorded in the CSV file. Like the last string of data that is been recorded - "588583492V,A B C Fernando,127180"

Comment: Have you used Debug sampler to verify if you are really getting the desired values in your variables.

Comment: @TestingWithArif The variables returns the exact values I need. And the other parts of the script is working perfect. What I need with the beanshell script is to export the variables as a comma separated string.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works perfectly for me. Can you confirm that are you using all of 'regular expression extractors' under same sampler? and Beanshell Post-processor is also under same sampler?

Answer (score 1):

How about writing it only when all variables are *not null*:

```
nic = vars.get("NicNo01");
name = vars.get("Name01");
loanId = vars.get("Loan_Id");

if(nic == null || name == null || loanId == null)
    return;

// otherwise write to file
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of high number of threads Beanshell may not be able to store the data properly due to performance issues. Try switching to [JSR223 Post Processor and use Groovy as scripting language](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

Another option could be using [sample_variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sample_variables=NicNo01,Name01,Loan_Id
```

and upon JMeter restart variables values will be added to JMeter's .jtl results file.